# How to make Windows right-click - Paste work in Linux vim?

Tags: terminal, clipboard, terminal-emulator, mobaxterm

When using MobaXTerm on Windows, I ssh into a Linux server, start vim and I can right-click into the terminal window and can choose Paste and it pastes text from the Windows clipboard.

When I use git bash in Windows, this does not work.

I do not see where in the toolchain I should set something to make this work with git bash.

I have seen some posts that were about configuring vim on the Linux server, but the MobaXTerm example shows that it should work without deep hacking of vim.

What configuration should I look into to make this work with git bash?